# MQL5 PositionSelect(_Symbol) call freezes test

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I'm hoping someone else has experienced this issue. I'm new to MQL5 (coming from pinescript) and finding my way around the language.

Following the guidelines of the documentation, it's recommended to call `PositionSelect()` before calling `PositionGetInteger()`, eg:

```
int openPositions(ENUM_POSITION_TYPE type) {
   int count = 0;
   
   //if (PositionSelect(_Symbol)) {
      for (long i = 0; i < PositionsTotal(); i++) {
          if (PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE, i) == type) {
              count++;
          }
      }
   //}
   return count;
}
```

If I enable that `PositionSelect(_Symbol)` condition, the MT5 back test "freezes" and does nothing after placing a few trades. I then have to click on Stop to restore functionality.

The code *seems* to work fine without that check, but the docs recommend that call and I've seen other tutorials using it too... so what the heck?

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got help via the MQL5.com forum. The answer is:

```
int openPositions(ENUM_POSITION_TYPE type) {
    int count = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < PositionsTotal(); i++) {
        if (!PositionGetTicket(i)) {
            Print("ERROR: PositionGetTicket() failed, error code: ", GetLastError());
            continue;
        }
        if (PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE) == type) 
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

The docs are confusing in this regard: both PositionGetTicket() and PositionSelect() are supposed to be used before PositionGetInteger(), but one freezes, and the other works.

oh well.